# join datasets with tfx tensorflow transform

Tags: apache-beam, tfx, tensorflow-transform

I am trying to replicate some data preprocessing that I have done in pandas into tensorflow transform.
I have a few CSV files, which I joined and aggregated with pandas to produce a training dataset. Now as part of productionising the model I would like this preprocessing to be done at scale with apache beam and tensorflow transform. However it is not quite clear to me how I can reproduce the same data manipulation there. Let's look at two main operations: `JOIN` dataset `a` and dataset `b` to produce `c` and group by `col1` on dataset `c`. This would be a quite straightforward operation in pandas, but how would I do this in tensorflow transform running on apache beam? Am I using the wrong tool for the job? What would be the right tool then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Beam Dataframes API](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) to do the join and other preprocessing exactly as you would have in Pandas. You can then use `to_pcollection` to get a PCollection that you can pass directly to your Tensorflow Transform operations, or save it as a file to read in later.

For top-level functions (such as merge) one needs to do

```
from apache_beam.dataframe.pandas_top_level_functions import pd_wrapper as beam_pd
```

and use operations `beam_pd.func(...)` in place of `pd.func(...)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have checked the beam dataframe API and it looks great, but I couldn't find anywhere an example of how to actually join the dataframes. Can you provide or link some example? thanks

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: that's for merging pandas dataframes, how would you merge a Beam Dataframe? would you still use pandas libraries? will it beam distribute it in a cluster?

Comment: pandas merge only accept dataframes, if i try to merge it i get `TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'apache_beam.dataframe.frames.DeferredDataFrame'> was passed`